# Mean of means and standard deviation into a boxplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization

How to make a boxplot with R that shows the mean of means of a sum variable and the standard deviation of the same sum variable? In this case, the mean of every row should be calculated as (x1 + x2 + x3) / 3. Then the mean of means comes from the column mean of `mean`.

Example dataframe

```
x1 <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
x2 <- c(6, 7, 4, 5, 7)
x3 <- c(4, 5, 3, 7, 1)

df <- data.frame(x1 = x1, x2 = x2, x3 = x3)

library(dplyr)
df <- df %>% 
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(
    sum_var = sum(c(x1, x2, x3)),
    mean = mean(c(x1, x2, x3))
  )
```

I'm looking for a regular boxplot like this:

[image]

So how to make boxplot like in the example picture, from a data like in my example?

Edit: I added the "mean" column into the dataframe and clarified the question

Edit: Boxplot example picture changed

Comment: So three will just be one box plot in the output rather than 4 as shown in your example?

Comment: Exactly @MrFlick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df %>% ungroup() %>% # because you had rowwise operations prior
  summarise(mean_of_means=mean(mean),
            stddev_of_means=sd(mean),
            mean_of_sum_vars = mean(sum_var),
            stddev_of_sums=sd(sum_var))

## A tibble: 1 × 4
#  mean_of_means stddev_of_means mean_of_sum_vars stddev_of_sums
#          <dbl>           <dbl>            <dbl>          <dbl>
#1          4.27           0.796             12.8           2.39

#In the y-axis there should be the mean_of_means. 
#Also, on the x-axis there shouldn't be a scale

ggplot(data=df)+
  aes(y=mean) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_blank()) + 
  scale_x_discrete()
```

[image]

Comment: yes I need code for the boxplot as well. Sorry for unclear communication

Comment: not sure if you want to boxplot sum_var or the related means, but you can easily switch.

Comment: In the y-axis there should be the mean_of_means. If I change it there, the entire plot goes grazy. Also, on the x-axis there shouldn't be a scale, just a point in thime, one measurement @Nir Graham

Comment: After your edit, it seems your answer solved my problem. Thank you very much! @Nir Graham